# Adding comment count to view

Tags: views, theming, comments

I want to be able to add a comment comment to a view , through comment.tpl.php as I have tried to add the comment counter through the admin area and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on the error?

I just did a quick test and was able to add comment count to a view:

Go to the views admin page , click fields, add

> Content: Comment count The number of comments a node has.

Comment: I have tried this and it hasnt worked ,the reason is most likely because when the view was developed (not by me), it was not  through the admin area